# Add a new column to the data frame where the new column is the smallest date value of a group where another column matches a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let me explain the question with an example,

```
def random_dates(start, end, n=10):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')
np.random.seed(42)
d = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': np.random.choice(['a','b','c'],size=10),
                       'BBB': np.random.choice([0,3,1],size=10),
                       'CCC': random_dates(pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'),pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'),10)})
```

d looks like this

```
  AAA  BBB   CCC
0   c   1   2017-06-08 23:18:17
1   a   1   2015-12-18 06:26:04
2   c   0   2016-05-11 01:34:40
3   c   1   2017-06-18 21:35:54
4   a   3   2016-12-21 11:51:05
5   a   0   2017-02-05 07:36:31
6   c   3   2016-06-25 13:49:15
7   b   3   2015-09-06 19:49:15
8   c   3   2016-11-28 00:06:38
9   c   3   2017-07-12 02:51:41
```

Now I want to add a new column which is min_date_value_per_AAAA whose value should be like this

```
j= d[d.BBB >0].groupby('AAA',as_index=False).CCC.min().rename(columns={"CCC":"min_CCC"})

    AAA min_CCC
0   a   2015-12-18 06:26:04
1   b   2015-09-06 19:49:15
2   c   2016-06-25 13:49:15
```

Notice that I dont want to take the min date value per group ,which is different from

```
d.groupby('AAA').CCC.min()

AAA
a   2015-12-18 06:26:04
b   2015-09-06 19:49:15
c   2016-05-11 01:34:40
```

Now I can join d with j and get min_CCC added to j by

```
 pd.merge(d,j,on="AAA",how="inner")

AAA BBB CCC min_CCC
0   c   1   2017-06-08 23:18:17 2016-06-25 13:49:15
1   c   0   2016-05-11 01:34:40 2016-06-25 13:49:15
2   c   1   2017-06-18 21:35:54 2016-06-25 13:49:15
3   c   3   2016-06-25 13:49:15 2016-06-25 13:49:15
4   c   3   2016-11-28 00:06:38 2016-06-25 13:49:15
5   c   3   2017-07-12 02:51:41 2016-06-25 13:49:15
6   a   1   2015-12-18 06:26:04 2015-12-18 06:26:04
7   a   3   2016-12-21 11:51:05 2015-12-18 06:26:04
8   a   0   2017-02-05 07:36:31 2015-12-18 06:26:04
9   b   3   2015-09-06 19:49:15 2015-09-06 19:49:15
```

My question is there a better way to achieve it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `transform`

```
d.CCC.where(d.BBB>0).groupby(d.AAA).transform('min')
Out[58]: 
0   2016-06-25 13:49:15
1   2015-12-18 06:26:04
2   2016-06-25 13:49:15
3   2016-06-25 13:49:15
4   2015-12-18 06:26:04
5   2015-12-18 06:26:04
6   2016-06-25 13:49:15
7   2015-09-06 19:49:15
8   2016-06-25 13:49:15
9   2016-06-25 13:49:15
Name: CCC, dtype: datetime64[ns]

d['new']=d.CCC.where(d.BBB>0).groupby(d.AAA).transform('min')
```

Comment: The thing is I want the minimum value of CCC  per group where BBB is > 0 ,else It would have worked .

Comment: Yes Got it , this is pretty neat

Comment: @Bg1850 ah :-) happy coding